# Compare the equality or no-equality bewteen two getters with Mockito

Tags: spring, mockito

Hello Everybody I have just started to do mocks with Mockito on a project and I clearly understand nothing ... I just want to check if two getters ( the ouvrage.getSociete() and the compte.getSociete()) in this else if() are equals or not equals to see the after treatment.

But in my test class, I tried to give them the same value and already there are some problems just for giving them value. So I think comparison won't be so easy too...

The ExportShapeAction I want to check:

```
@Namespace("/front")
@ParentPackage("gu-default")
@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef("guStack")
})
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
public class ExportShapeAction extends FrontAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3228513581235888117L;

    @Autowired
    private JetonAccesService jetonAccesService;
    
    @Autowired
    private OuvrageManager ouvrageManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private OuvrageSasManager ouvrageSasManager;
    
    private Long idOuvrage;

    @org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action(value = "exportShape", results = {
            @Result(name = Action.SUCCESS, params = { "actionName", "mesouvrages", "namespace", "/front" }, type = "redirectAction"),
            @Result(name = Action.ERROR, location = "/WEB-INF/jsp/front/mesouvrages/mesouvrages.jsp"),
    })
    public String demandeExportShape() {
        Compte compte = getCompteCourant();
        Ouvrage ouvrage = ouvrageManager.get(idOuvrage);
        if (ouvrage == null) {
            this.addActionError("Export Shape depuis la publication impossible : l'ouvrage n'est pas encore publié");
            return Action.ERROR;
        } else if (!ouvrage.getSociete().equals(compte.getSociete())) {
            this.addActionError("Vous n'avez pas les droits requis sur l'ouvrage");
            return Action.ERROR;
        }
        try {
            jetonAccesService.demandeExportZoneOuvrage(compte.getCompteId(), idOuvrage, false, false);
            this.addActionMessage("Votre demande d’export est enregistrée. Vous recevrez un courriel de confirmation avec le lien de téléchargement lorsque celle-ci sera finalisée.");
        } catch (FonctionnelleException e) {
            // specification du message
            if ("Doublon".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getTitre())) {
                List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
                messages.add("Une demande d’export est déjà en cours de traitement.");
                e.setMessages(messages);
            }
            this.addFonctionnelleExceptionToActionErrors(e);
            return Action.ERROR;
        }

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
```

The ExportShapeActionTest class I have created with the mockito

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExportShapeActionTest.class)

public class ExportShapeActionTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ExportShapeAction exportShapeManager;

    @Spy
    private CompteManager compteManager;
    
    @Spy
    private SocieteManager societeManager;

    @Spy
    private OuvrageManager ouvrageManager;

    public void testDemandeExportShapeParamOkOuvrageOkCompteOk() {

        
        Societe societe1 = new Societe();
        Societe societe2 = new Societe();
        
        Long id = new Long(4);

        exportShapeManager.setIdOuvrage(id);
        
        
        Ouvrage ouvrage = Mockito.mock(Ouvrage.class);
        Compte compte = Mockito.mock(Compte.class);

        
        Mockito.when(ouvrage.getSociete()).thenReturn(societe1); 
        Mockito.when(compte.getSociete()).thenReturn(societe2); 

        // Act
        String result = exportShapeManager.demandeExportShape();

        // Assert
        Assertions.assertEquals("error", result);
```

[image: The errors I get Kaminsky]

Comment: there is no return statement in `demandeExportShape` method. Can you please check it out?

Comment: I have edited the post with the entire function ! It's what you wanted ?

Comment: Yes, great. Can you share the error you have faced too?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know in the comments if I don't clearly understand your question.

The goal of using Mockito is to isolate your particular unit from other dependencies. That's why I believe you should mark `CompteManager` and `OuvrageManager` with `@Mock` annotation.

Then try to use this way of mocking method calls. Instead of:

```
Mockito.doReturn(ouvrage).when(ouvrageManager).get(id);
Mockito.doReturn(compte).when(compteManager).get(id);
```

Use this way:

```
Mockito.when(ouvrageManager.get(id)).thenReturn(ouvrage);
Mockito.when(compteManager.get(id)).thenReturn(compte);
```

Comment: I have done the @Mock change on both managers and the 2 lines ! but I still get errors, I have edited my post with the image of the new errors if you can see.

Comment: You need to set `idOuvrage`,  error message says that

Comment: Ok I have added the code for the ExportShapeAction and do an exportShapeManager.setIdOuvrage(id); and edited my code trying to give value to ouvrage.getSociete() and compte.getSociete() but now I have a nullPointerException ...

Comment: @AloïsCoussout it's pretty difficult to find error without up-to-date codebase

Comment: I have edited the post for the classTest, There is a missing information for you ?

Comment: Ok I have reedited the classtest I'm near the goal but now it throws me a null value althougth I'm waiting for an error value and I sincerely don't know why ... Kaminsky my friend help me ^^